# Java profiler tool for webservice

Tags: java, profiler

I am building a project which runs in SOA architecture. It is implemented with jersey framework and runs on embedded Jetty server. Is there any Java profiler that can be used for such a setup that is easily pluggable?

Comment: You mean you wnat to test a webservice call or profile your application? If the former try fidler2 or SOAPUI

Answer (score 1):

Any Java profiler will be able to profile the VM that runs the embedded Jetty server. As for being "pluggable", most modern profilers can attach to Java 6+ JVMs without any special startup command modifications.

Apart from [visualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), I recommend [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), whose **servlet probe** will show you all invoked URLs. In the servlet probe, you can configure which parts of the URL are retained, so that you get a useful hot spot definition.

[image: servlet probe settings]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.